# Does @EJB in JAVA EE load models to be used on the page?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In this tutorial: http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/ee/servlet

Is `@EJB GuestDao guestDao;` merely a way of loading the model on the page so it can be used?  If I wasn't in a servlet and didn't have access to `@EJB` how would I load the model?  Can I load models from other models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@EJB GuestDao guestDao;
```

With that you are defining your servlet's (could be another ejb) dependecy on the ejb `GuestDao`. When the servlet is instantiated by the container, it makes sure that it injects the ejb (servlet's dependency) into the servlet.

It works on local ejbs, whereas if it were a remote ejb then you would have to do a JNDI lookup.

Check out the [API Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html).

Alternative to that would be to use something called [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html). Which can be injected into the servlet by by using the annotation [`@PersistenceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) if you are using container managed persistence. But you can also create it programmatically (when you are not in a servlet and don't have access to `@EJB`) by using [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html).

See example of how you would do that in a desktop application [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/persistenceapi/).